# Timer for quiz should start once the page is completley loaded in JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am developing an online quiz application in PHP and I am able to execute it well, but the problem is, the timer should start working only when the complete page is loaded. I used `onload="starttimer()"` function and then in the `starttimer()` I implemented all the code I need to run the timer. When I use `window.stop();` to stop the page's loading, the page stopped loading but the timer keeps on running. What can I do to avoid this? Please help me!!

Comment: Why would you use window.stop?

Comment: Just implement a method to the time which stops it. Don't stop it by window.stop() it's not static content..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think you want to use `setinterval();` to control you timer which needs to run asynchronously because there isn't any threading in javascript. So when you call `window.stop();` you can also call `clearInterval();` Then when you wanted to restart the timer either you can start it from the beginning again or you use html to contain your value.

In the example the timer would initially start with 40 seconds

```
var quiz_interval = setInterval(updateTimer, 1000);
function updateTimer(){
  var time_remaining = parseInt($('#timer').html());
  if(time_remaining  == 0){//dosomething}
  else{ $("#timer").html(time_remaining--);}
  //logic to check if timer has gone down to zero if not write the new number 
  //to the div

}


<html><body>
    <div id="timer">40</div>
</body></html>
```